# How to select week number between different year in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get data and week number in 2018, but I have 2017 data and 2018 in one database.

I try this:

```
DECLARE @sub_week AS INT 
SET @sub_week='01'

SELECT 
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -1, Day)) Week, day, RTP
FROM 
    [Daily Beyond]
WHERE 
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -1, Day)) = @sub_week
```

but the result I get data 2017.

How can I get data in 2018?

Comment: Since your `@sub_week` is an `INT`, you should **NOT** initialize it with a string, but with an **INT** instead: `SET @sub_week = 1;` .....

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sub_week as int;
set @sub_week='01';
SELECT datepart(WEEK,DATEADD(year,1,datecolumn)) AS Wk, 
       datepart(day,DATEADD(year,1,datecolumn)) as day,
       dateNAME(w,DATEADD(year,1,datecolumn)) as Weekday,
       RTP
  FROM [Daily Beyond]
      WHERE datepart(WEEK,DATEADD(year,1,datecolumn))= @sub_week;
```